# Compare list items with variable

Tags: velocity

I am trying to do in velocity a search in a list. I have a list of country codes that i set like this:

```
#set($Europe=(['ee','ja','ku','aa' ])
```

I have a variable($cntryCode), already set that i want to compare with each item in the list in order to see if the country is from that region (in this case Europe, or if it is not).

I did:

```
#foreach ($cntryCode in $Europe)
#set ($region="Europe")
#end
```

But it does not work.
Also, i have tried:

```
#if ($Europe.contains($cntryCode)
#set($regio="Europe")
#end
#end
```

But does not work neither.

That is my first problem, then I need to set more than one region to some countries... any idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

not sure what you are exactly trying to do, but works for me is the following, i.e. iterating over the list and checking if the element is found:

```
## pre-set by some other code
#set($cntrCode = 'ja')

#set($Europe=(['ee','ja','ku','aa' ]) ) 

#foreach ($eu in $Europe)
#if($eu.equals($cntrCode))
    found country code $cntrCode in $Europe
#end
#end
```

$Europe in this case seems to be of type java.lang.ArrayList, so what also works is the following

```
#if($Europe.contains($cntrCode))
    found country code $cntrCode in $Europe.class
#end
```

I hope that helps you to get started, otherwise the [Velocity User Guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/user-guide.html) and the other documents should also provide useful information for how to handle these kind of things in Velocity.